# Why does subform get focus in Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a main form, ClientInfoForm, and a subform, EditTransactions_subform on a tabbed page. When I click on the tab containing the subform, the subform gets the focus, and not a control on the tab. The subform is in datasheet view. I would like the focus to go to a control on the tabbed page, and not the subform. It seems that the leftmost column on the subform gets the focus. How do I correct this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Sincerely,
Howard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set TabIndex property of the controls. Whatever control you want to first get focus should be set to 0.

Comment: The TabIndex property is 0, but it doesn't get the focus consistently. When I page back and forth between the tabs, sometimes the control gets the focus, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I changed the TabStop on the subform to "No" and that seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for giving me credit for an accepted answer, although not quite deserved. I meant to mention the TabStop property and forgot.